# Mongo JSON doesn't parse like a dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb

I am extracting this following JSON from my MongoDB, however, when I try to loop through the "data" it the loop returns it like I am parsing a string rather than giving me the elements of the JSON.

```
    {'_id': ObjectId('5c0a3626c33f166b5bf387bc'), 
    'pos_date': '2018-12-07', 
    'data': '{"SRG": 0.0, "URO": 0.0, "FLT": 0.0, "SDC": 0.0, "EXE": 0.0, ..... }
```

When I run this code:

```
    pos = posts['data']
        for p in pos:
            print (p)
```

I get the results letter by letter rather than as the elements of the JSON.

```
    {
    "
    S
    R
    G
    "
    :

    0
    .
    0
    ,

    "
    U
```

Must be a simple mistake I've made.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I appears you've mistakenly stored your `data` value as a JSON string, rather than an object.

Answer (score 1):

It is a string.

To parse it as json, do

```
import json

pos = json.loads(posts['data'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `posts['data']` is a string and in python, a string is like a list of characters which is why you got the response in your question.

The code below however decodes the json string to python `dict`. Cheers

```
import json

posts = json.loads(posts['data'])
```